# How to open IE webdriver instance as non admin?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Im using a tool to invoke the following method to launch an IE instance.

```
string driverPath = path                           
InternetExplorerDriverService service = 
InternetExplorerDriverService.CreateDefaultService(@driverPath);
service.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;
InternetExplorerOptions options = new InternetExplorerOptions();
options.IntroduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings = true;
options.EnablePersistentHover = false;
driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(service, options);
```

The tool has to be opened using administrator so after this method runs, the browser is also opened as an admin, however website i need to access doesnt work if the browser is opened as an administrator.

Is there any way to launch the browser as a non-admin?